# ImageTransformation: polar to cartesian

Tags: image-processing, coordinate-transformation

I am working on something that requires the polar transformation of some images. I implemented this transformation with `ImageTransformation`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cV4T.jpg"]
```

[image]

```
{center, radius} = ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalComponents[img, 0.2], 
    {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[1, 2]];
polar = ImageTransformation[img, center + {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]}*#[[2]] &, 
    {2 Pi radius, radius}, DataRange -> Full,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 360 \[Degree]}, {1, radius}}]
```

[image]

After some processing I would like to transform the image back into the original coordinate system. This step is where I ran into problems. The transformation of the coordinates isn't really the problem but I couldn't figure out how to center the transformation properly and what `PlotRange` I have to provide.
**So the question is how to reverse the transformation:**

```
ImageTransformation[img, center + {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]}*#[[2]] &, 
    {2 Pi radius, radius}, DataRange -> Full,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 360 \[Degree]}, {1, radius}}]
```

One of my failed attempts:

```
ImageTransformation[imgNorm, {0, Pi radius} + {Sqrt[#[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2], 
    ArcTan[#[[2]]/#[[1]]]} &, {2 radius, 2 radius}, DataRange -> Full]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
ImageTransformation[polar, 
 {ArcTan @@ (radius - #), Norm[# - radius]} &, 
 {2 radius, 2 radius}, 
 DataRange -> {{-180 \[Degree], 180 \[Degree]}, {1, radius}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2 radius}, {0, 2 radius}}]
```

Notes:

- Don't call `ArcTan[y/x]`. You'd only get an angle between -90°..90°. There's an overload `ArcTan[x,y]` that returns an angle from -180°..180°
- Somewhat unintuitively, `PlotRange->Full` *isn't* the same as `PlotRange->(* dimensions of output image*)`, it uses the *input* image's dimensions. If in doubt, give explicit ranges.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for. Replacing the 1 in the `DataRange` option with 0 gets rid of the black dot in the middle.

Comment: @paw: The black dot is there because the `polar` image contains no data for that location. If you use 0 in the `DataRange` of the inverse transform, but used 1 in the `PlotRange` of the polar transform, the result will be slightly skewed (by 1 pixel at the center). You can either use 0 for both, or use `Padding -> "Fixed"` to get rid of the black dot in the center.

Comment: @paw and @nikie : Thanks a lot for both of your code examples that are very helpful to me. However, could you please explain why `({x,y} + {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]}*#[[2]] &)` does what it is doing in `ImageTransormation`? Because I tried to understand the transformation by using a list of pixel positions, e.g. `{{1,1},{1,2},...,{2,1},{2,2}...} and the transformed pixel positions on which I applied the above equation and displayed the results using `ListPlot`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @paw and @nikie : My motivation is that I want to use an arbitrary vector `center={x,y}` about which to tranform the image in polar coordinates. But I get problems with the settings I need to use for PlotRange in order to display the whole transformed image. Thank you!