# Averaging over a circle from FFT to plot the amplitude vs wavelength

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis

I am trying to calculate the amplitude of FFT vs wavelength for some experiments. I had put a question here previously on how to compute the FFT of an image. Thanks to everyone who provided the direction. I have prepared the program with some modifications and have computed the FFT. First here's the link to the previous question: [Previous question on calculation of FFT](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87214)

Here's the raw data: [image: raw data]

I have computed the following code to calculate the FFT:

```
data = MeanFilter[img,0]
fft1 = Fourier[ImageData[data][[All, All, 2]]];
Floor[Dimensions[fft1]/2]];
fft1 = RotateLeft[fft1, Floor[Dimensions[fft1]/2]];
```

I have analyzed the image and found it to be a RGBA image.I have used this code to evaluate the FFT for other two channels 1 and 3 and then added up the absolute part of FFT. Once we get the FFT pattern, which looks like this [image: FFT image]. My target is to compute the amplitude vs wavelength which will effectively give me the period of these patterns. What I wish to do is to average the FFT over circles. As from my previous post you can see that I tried to do that defining a circle of a certain radius with the no. of pixels being the radius. However, I want to know is it a good method? The result is now what I expected.

If you want to exactly know what I am aiming for here's an example. ([ref:](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1202/1202.5128.pdf))
And the portion which matches well with what I want to do.[image: desired result]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you get your FFT image. If I apply a discrete Fourier transform to your image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lquy0.jpg"];
pixels = ImageData[img][[All, All, 2]];    
pixels = pixels - Mean[Flatten@pixels];
```

(Setting the data to 0 mean removes the bright spot in the center of the FFT - the bin for frequency 0.)

```
wnd1d = N@Array[HammingWindow, #, {-.5, .5}] & /@ Dimensions[pixels];    
wnd = Outer[Times, wnd1d[[1]], wnd1d[[2]]];
Image[wnd]
```

(I'm using a Hamming window here - if you don't, the image borders will produce slight artifacts in the result, because the Fourier transform is periodic.)

```
fft = Fourier[wnd*pixels];
fft = RotateLeft[fft, Floor[Dimensions[fft]/2]];    
Image[Rescale@Abs[fft]]
```

[image]

This looks more or less as you expected, right? The bright area in the center are low frequencies - maybe an artifact of the image acquisition process? (E.g. if you scanned the image from a book, it would be slightly darker to one side of the page, that would produce low-frequency peaks like that. Or maybe it's the green text in the image? It *does* make the image brighter to the lower right, on average.)

Now if you use the polar transform code [from my last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87240/242):

```
radius = Sqrt[Total[Dimensions[fft]^2]]/2.;
fftPolar = 
 ImageTransformation[
  Image[Abs[fft]], {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]} #[[2]] &, 
  Round[{\[Pi]*radius, radius}], PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 1}}, 
  DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]

ListLogPlot[Mean /@ ImageData[fftPolar, DataReversed -> True], 
 DataRange -> {0, radius}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

You get this:

[image]

So what does that plot mean? To be honest, I can never remember myself. So I'll generate a simple test image with a known frequency pattern:

```
testFrequency = 25;
pixels = Array[
   Sin[Norm[{#1, #2} - 0.5 Dimensions[pixels]]*2 π/testFrequency] &, 
   Dimensions[pixels]];
Image[pixels]
```

[image]

which gives this Fourier transform:

[image]

and the polar developed view looks like this:

[image]

where the peak of the mean plot is at:

```
meanData = Mean /@ ImageData[fftPolar, DataReversed -> True];
maxIndex = Position[meanData, Max[meanData]][[1, 1]]
```

> 51

Which can be understood as "there are 51 full sine waves in 2*radius", i.e. the estimated frequency would be `2*radius / maxIndex == 25.1`, which is quite close to the original frequency 25 I used to generate the test pattern.