# Visualize transformation used in multiple integration

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, regions

In class, we will sketch the region $D$ in $R^2$ bounded by the curves $xy=1$, $xy=4$, $y=x$, and $y=x+2$. Then we will use the change of variables given by $u=xy$ and $v=y-x$. We need to show that this change of variables maps region $D^*=\{(u,v): 1\le u\le 4,\ 0\le v\le 2\}$ onto the region $D$.

Now, I know how to use *Mathematica* to sketch both of these regions, but I wonder if folks here could share code for visualizing how the indicated transformation transforms one region into the other.

Comment: Have you seen `TransformedRegion[]`?

Comment: In addition to @Guesswhoitis. suggestion, it could be fun to illustrate things with [ImageTransformation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58495/245). E.g., if you take an image with a regular pattern on it, then the transformation will also help explain the change in density that corresponds to the Jacobi determinant.

Answer (score 9):

Not so fancy as transforming an image, but I like how the mesh in `ParametricPlot`
shows the deformation.

```
{chvar} = Simplify[
  Solve[u == x y && v == y - x && y > 0 && x > 0, {x, y}, Reals],
  1 <= u <= 4 && 0 <= v <= 2]
(*  {{x -> (2 u)/(v + Sqrt[4 u + v^2]), y -> 1/2 (v + Sqrt[4 u + v^2])}}  *)

With[{mesh = Range[-4, 6, 1/4]},
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{x, y} /. chvar, {u, 0.002, 6}, {v, -4, 4}, Mesh -> {mesh, mesh}],
  ParametricPlot[{x, y} /. chvar, {u, 1, 4}, {v, 0, 2}, Mesh -> {mesh, mesh},
    PlotStyle -> Red]
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Each mesh quadrilateral is the image of a square in the `uv` plane with the same dimensions `1/4` x `1/4`.  The difference of the areas in the graphics represents the Jacobian factor.

(Note that the mesh was chosen explicitly to make the boundary align with the mesh.)

---

With `ElementMesh` you can color the mesh according to the area.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
uvmesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{1, 0}, {4, 2}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1/4}];

dx = Function[{u, v}, x - u /. chvar // Evaluate];
dy = Function[{u, v}, y - v /. chvar // Evaluate];

dxifn = ElementMeshInterpolation[{uvmesh}, dx @@@ uvmesh["Coordinates"]];
dyifn = ElementMeshInterpolation[{uvmesh}, dy @@@ uvmesh["Coordinates"]];

xymesh = ElementMeshDeformation[uvmesh, {dxifn, dyifn}];

With[{mesh = Range[-4, 6, 1/4]},
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{x, y} /. chvar, {u, 0.002, 6}, {v, -4, 4}, Mesh -> {mesh, mesh}],
  Graphics[
   ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[xymesh, All] /.
    Polygon[pp_] :> Riffle[
      ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ 
       Rescale[First@ElementMeshElementMeasure[xymesh]],
      Polygon /@ pp]],
  xymesh["Wireframe"]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why have `Method -> Reduce` here?

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks. It's an artifact of the first thing I tried failing.  Forgot to see if it was ultimately necessary, which it's not.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought it might have been to deal with backward compatibility or something.